# Using Numpy to write a function that returns all rows of A that have completely distinct entries

Tags: python, numpy

For example:
For

```
A = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 4, 4],
    [5, 6, 6]])
```

I want to get the output
`array([[1, 2, 3]])`.
For `A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)`,
I want to get

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

WITHOUT using loops

Comment: Please don't deface your question after an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
B = np.sort(A, axis=1)

out = A[(B[:,:-1] != B[:, 1:]).all(1)]
```

Or using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

out = A[pd.DataFrame(A).nunique(axis=1).eq(A.shape[1])]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```